# Get image from DB, rename the image on server and save new image name in DB with PHP

Tags: php, linux, image, file

I have the image name stored in the database and the images are stored on the server. What I need to do now, fetch the images and rename the images with new name which is in this case same name as ID from the database.

Here is my current code.

```
<?php

//open the database 
include '../db/dbc.php';

$getimage = mysql_query("SELECT id, profile_image_url FROM users WHERE profile_image_url !='' ");

while($image = mysql_fetch_array($getimage)) {

    //complete image name to the original image 
    $imgdir = "../images/profile/".$image['profile_image_url']; //path where image is + image name 


    $imagename = $image['profile_image_url']; //image name old EXAMPLE: 7823jhasjda6732iojhaksd.jpg
    $id = $image['id']; //id of the user


    $temp = explode(".", $imagename);
    $newfilename = $id . '.' . end($temp); // new image name with id EXAMPLE: 1023.jpg



    move_uploaded_file($imgdir,"../images/profile/".$newfilename);

}


?>
```

So I'm managing to fetch the images, and create the new name which works fine but the move_uploaded_file doesn't work for some reason. 
What i need to do now is to rename the old image on the server with the new image name generated in $newfile varialble.

Any help would be appriciated.

Cheerz

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file` is for moving an uploaded file from the temporary upload location to its final destination. While your image was probably uploaded at some point, it doesn't count as such anymore. The function expects the first parameter to be *just* a filename, and looks for it in that upload folder.

In your case, the function should have returned false, so if something is not working, please check the result value of the function, and check [what it means](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

You're probably looking for [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php), which is linked from the page about `move_uploaded_file`, and which can also 'rename' (move) files to a different folder and even a different partition.

Answer (score 0):

I used rename yes. This is my final solution.

```
<?php

//open the database 
include '../db/dbc.php';

$getimage = mysql_query("SELECT id, profile_image_url FROM users WHERE profile_image_url !='' ");

while($image = mysql_fetch_array($getimage)) {

    //complete image name to the original image 
    $imgdir = "../images/profile/".$image['profile_image_url']; //path where image is + image name 


    $imagename = $image['profile_image_url']; //image name old EXAMPLE: 7823jhasjda6732iojhaksd.jpg
    $id = $image['id']; //id of the user


    $temp = explode(".", $imagename);
    $newfilename = $id . '.' . end($temp); // new image name with id EXAMPLE: 1023.jpg

    $newdir = "../images/profile/".$newfilename;


    rename($imgdir,$newdir);

}
```

?>